# how come the result in the below two cases is different?

Tags: java, set, equals

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
String s2 = new String("rajkumar");
String s3 = new String("rajkumar");

set2.add(s3);
set2.add(s2);
System.out.println(set2.size()); //this will output 1


Person p1= new Person("rajkumar", 25);
Person p2= new Person("rajkumar", 25);
Set<Person>set= new HashSet<>();

set.add(p1);
set.add(p2);
System.out.println(set.size());//This will output 2
```

why is this happening. Isn't the has hashcode of a string objects should be different?

here person class is like

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dbl as i am using new to declare new strings object i dont think it will be using strings from string pool

Comment: `Set` will call `equals` for equality. s2 and s3 are equal

Answer (score 2):

`Set` allows unique entries. Uniqueness is checked by `equals` method.
Both s2 and s3 have same text hence both are equal. String class implements `equals` method for text comparison. On adding s3 to existing set, s3 object does not get added, instead the method returns false saying that object with same value already exists.

Person class on other hand does not implement equals and hashcode, hence the references are compared. In this case both objects get added to the set

Go through [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) for more information.

Comment: so String class is by default implemented with equals method?

Comment: yes, all data classes in library implements equals and hashcode

Answer (score 1):

In Java there is String pool, which saves equal Strings in the same memory. Look at this link: https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool.
if you want the same Person in once in Set you must override equals method.

Answer (score 1):

> The Java Set interface, java.util.Set, represents a collection of objects where each object in the Set is unique. In other words, the same object cannot occur more than once in a Java Set.
>   [source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/set.html#implementations)

A Hashset is backed by a hashmap

set2 is of type String. Both s2 and s3 are considered identical strings and so only one entry exists in set2

set takes objects of type Person and p1 and p2 are different objects despite the fact they have identical fields.

To test this further change the string value of s2 or s3 and also try creating equals and hashcode methods in your Person class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return age == person.age &&
            Objects.equals(name, person.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this post: [Can a set have duplicate elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011475/can-a-set-have-duplicate-elements). Here are well explained how `set` works.
But if we look at your question, your two `Strings` are both same(`equals` compare). For other hand `Person` `object` does not same. If you want `Person` `objects` works as `String` you should [overide equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java) in your `class`.